# How do i make a field in an interface conditionaly optional or required in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

Im using typescript with react and i want a component to require a prop `DragActions` ONLY if that question is a `isDraggable` = true.

i tried something like this, knowing it probably isn't right.

```
type IDragPayload = {
  dragHandleProps: any;
};
type TDragActions = {
  isDraggable : true, dragActions : IDragPayload
} | {isDraggable : false, dragActions? : never};

interface IQuestionCard
{
    isDraggable:boolean;
    DragActions : TDragActions;
}

const foo:IQuestionCard = {
    isDraggable : false
}
```

Comment: That looks about right. You only need to make `parentQuestion` optional -> `parentQuestion?: never`

Comment: hmm i just tried that, but when i mount the component with prop isSubQuestion=true , typescript doesnt complain at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just make `parentQuestion` optional :

```
type TParentQuestion = {
    isSubQuestion: true,
    parentQuestion: Question
} | { isSubQuestion: false, parentQuestion?: never }


interface Question {
    isSubQuestion?: boolean,
    parentQuestion: TParentQuestion
}

declare const question: Question;

const foo: TParentQuestion = { //OK
    isSubQuestion: false
}

const bar: TParentQuestion = { // OK
    isSubQuestion: true,
    parentQuestion: question
}

const baz: TParentQuestion = { // KO
    isSubQuestion: false,
    parentQuestion: question
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgCgQwE4QHbAIoFcIGdgCWA9qlALxQDeAUFHVAbgMpYBG2ehJAXFMEjgA0temGRpMOfMVS8O0ktQC%20UAD5UGzNvK6yoAMwQAbXBEFQxKdDpkB%20XqggA3CEihLqnguleGAxtA2JFQidIws7FK69lCsRERGEAiowvQW4tZRMrzwGZKcMsqeACYQfkbiUH4k%20FAAjlk8UEGoANye1ai1%20vE5iFb5CqQUlFAA9GMA8gDSoZoRLbyGJhBF1J21rMh9eS3kGhNQM3Ph2o16-EJzlhKL9edrG8CxCABeOwN7I%20NjUNOTJy0kQKTWWplSol2514DRBqGUQA)

Comment: actually ive ran into a problem here, youre intializing the variable with the type, i actually wanted to use the interface that will also inherit the conditionality of the type but for one specific field, could you check my edit for me ? thanks!